# Is there a legal term for a natural person acting under the name of a company?

Tags: legal-terms

For example, if a post is made online under the name of a company, that post will be made under the name of the legal entity (company), but it had to be written by an actual natural person operating within that company.

Is there a legal term that describes this junction (a natural person acting on behalf of a company)? Is it simply "representation" or is there some more accurate term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_agency)

All actions of a company must, of necessity, be made by a natural person because companies are legal fictions - the law treats them as if they are real but they aren't. When a person acts for somebody else, the relevant branch of law is agency law - that person is an agent of the company principal.

Answer (score 0):

While "agent" is indeed the most general term here, for some purposes only an officer of the company can act for it, and so the proper term is "officer" in such cases.